# Can't get custom JSONP pipeline to work

Tags: php, proxy, jsonp

I'm building an audio player that makes 3 different API calls, and I need them all to be in JSONP format, so I made a PHP proxy file that determines the output of the JSON data like so:

```
$datatype = $_GET["type"];
$artist = urlencode($_GET["artist"]);
$album = urlencode($_GET["album"]);
$content = "";

if($datatype == 'albumart'){
    $content = file_get_contents('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=037358e302c80571663e6a7a66b1dc05&artist=' . $artist . '&album=' . $album . '&format=json');
} elseif($datatype == 'artistart'){
    $content = file_get_contents('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&api_key=037358e302c80571663e6a7a66b1dc05&artist=' . $artist . '&autocorrect=1&format=json');
} else {
    $content = file_get_contents('http://cjzn.streamon.fm/metadata/recentevents/CJZN-48k.json');
}

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($content) . ')';
```

Upon testing the output it seems to work fine, it gets the respective API data, wraps it in the JSONP `()` and accepts a JSONP callback.

Bur when I try and use it in my Javascript file it doesn't seem to work, but I can't figure out why! Here's an example of one of the functions being used to call the JSON data:

```
function getAlbumArt(artist,album){
    var dataArtist = artist,
        dataAlbum = album,
        albumArtURL;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'jsonproxy.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: {
                type: 'albumart',
                artist: dataArtist,
                album: dataAlbum
        },
        success: function(data) {
                if(data.album.image[4]["#text"]){
                    var albumArtURL = data.album.image[4]["#text"];
                    $('section.player div.album-artwork').css({'background-image':'url("' + albumArtURL + '")'});
                } else {
                        getArtistArt(dataArtist);
                }
        },
        error: function() {
                getArtistArt(dataArtist);
                alert('Sorry, unable to retrieve album artwork!');
        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone help with why this doesn't work for me?

**Edit**

I did `alert(data);` on `success`, and that returned all of the data from the feed, after that if I did something more specific like `alert(data.album.image[4]["#text"]);` it returned `undefined`. Very confused here. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked the console log in your browser? This should tell you if and why its failing.

Comment: Currently not at a computer but I will check when I get to one. Just for clarity sake, what I'm doing is possible, right? It's just a problem with my implementation?

Comment: In lieu of the console I did a good old `alert` to alert some of the data when the function ran, and the alert returned undefined. This makes me think it's something with the PHP file or my Ajax request in jQuery. Just not sure where, I've looked over and over

Comment: Oddly enough I got it to work when I removed the JSON encoding to `$content` in the PHP file!